# How to Submit Form Data into MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, form-submit, homestead, laravel-5.8

I am relatively new to Laravel and coding in general. I am trying to use Eloquent and to pass data from my form into a MySQL database. I can "submit" without any errors but don't see the data in the table. I feel like my code is getting messier as I am trying to figure this out and I would love a review of my code. I've tried several different ways of doing this by reading through tutorials, books and reviewing other people's code.

**Route**

```
Route::post('submit', function (Request $request) {
    $data = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'category' => 'required|max:255',
        'content' => 'required|max:900',
    ]);
    return redirect('submit');
});
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

public function store(Request $request)
{
    Post::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'category' => $request->category,
        'content' => $request->content,
    ]);

    return redirect('views.submit');
}
```

View/Blade

```
<div>
    <form action='' method='post'>
        @csrf
        <p><label>Title</label><br/>
            <input type='text' name='title' value=''><?php if (isset($error)) {
                echo $_POST['title'];
            }?></p>
        <p><label>Category</label><br/>
            <textarea name='category' cols='60' rows='10'><?php if (isset($error)) {
                    echo $_POST['category'];
                }?></textarea></p>
        <p><label>Content</label><br/>
            <textarea name='content' cols='60' rows='10'><?php if (isset($error)) {
                    echo $_POST['content'];
                }?></textarea></p>
        <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm expecting this to pass data to my table named "blogs."

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin I will definitely make those changes. I briefly read through the links you included and will need to spend some time with it. Could you tell me what I'm missing from my code that is preventing the data to be moved to the SQL database?

Comment: On the label suggestion would this accomplish what you are suggesting?

<p><label for = "Title"></label><br />
<input type='text' name='title' id='title'><?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['title'];}?></p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solved this after making several changes.

The first thing I did was moved my controller to /app/books.php

I simplified the code to the following:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class books extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'author',
        'category',
    ];
}
```

I then modified the route to NOT include the redirect:

```
Route::post('/submitbook', function (Request $request) {
    $data = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'author' => 'required|max:255',
        'category' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);
```

Perhaps the biggest resolution happened by a fluke. I was working on a separate issue and had to clear my known_hosts file and everything worked after.